# New version of Latex generates a smaller number of pages?

Tags: ieeetran

From the same .tex file, when I compile at my office, latex generates a 11-page PDF file. When I compile at home, it generates a 10-page file.

Here is the version of latex in my office:

```
qsp30@hydrogen-pc ~> latex -version
pdfTeX using libpoppler 3.141592-1.40.3-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.6)
kpathsea version 3.5.6
Copyright 2007 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Kpathsea is copyright 2007 Karl Berry and Olaf Weber.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX using libpoppler copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX using libpoppler source.
Primary author of pdfTeX using libpoppler: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Kpathsea written by Karl Berry, Olaf Weber, and others.

Compiled with libpng 1.2.46; using libpng 1.2.49
Compiled with zlib 1.2.5; using zlib 1.2.5
Compiled with libpoppler
```

I'm in my office at the moment, so I don't know the version of my latex at home, but I installed it this February, so I believe it is latest.

My question is if this is true, or I'm missing something. In order to make sure that I use the same class file, I used absolute path in both cases:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, conference]{../latex/IEEE/IEEEtran}
```

---

### UPDATE

As I guess, the latex that generated 11 page pdf is much older. But I don't know which packages caused this difference. Here are my two file lists:

---

```
 *File List*
IEEE/IEEEtran.cls
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
 amsmath.sty    2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
 amssymb.sty    2002/01/22 v2.2d
amsfonts.sty    2001/10/25 v2.2f
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2006/02/20 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2007/01/08 v0.04d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
verbatim.sty    2003/08/22 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
listings.sty    2004/10/17 1.3b (Carsten Heinz)
lstpatch.sty    2004/10/17 1.3b (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2004/09/07 1.3 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2004/09/05 1.3 listings configuration
multirow.sty    
rotating.sty    1997/09/26, v2.13 Rotation package
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
   color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 wrapfig.sty    2003/01/31  v 3.6
booktabs.sty    2005/03/16 v1.6180 publication quality tables
   array.sty    2005/08/23 v2.4b Tabular extension package (FMi)
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
     url.sty    2005/06/27  ver 3.2  Verb mode for urls, etc.
algpseudocode.sty    
algorithmicx.sty    2005/04/27 v1.2 Algorithmicx
 parskip.sty    2001/04/09 non-zero parskip adjustments
flushend.sty    1997/10/01
lstlang1.sty    2004/09/05 1.3 listings language file
    umsa.fd    2002/01/19 v2.2g AMS font definitions
    umsb.fd    2002/01/19 v2.2g AMS font definitions
  ot1pcr.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/pcr.
  omsptm.fd    
lstlang1.sty    2004/09/05 1.3 listings language file
 lstmisc.sty    2004/09/07 1.3 (Carsten Heinz)
  paper.bbl
```

---

File list when generating 10 pages.

```
 *File List*
IEEEtran.cls    2012/11/21 V1.8c by Harald Hanche-Olsen and Anders Christensen
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
verbatim.sty    2003/08/22 v1.5q LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
listings.sty    2013/08/26 1.5b (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2013/08/26 1.5b (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2013/08/26 1.5b listings configuration
multirow.sty    
rotating.sty    2009/03/28 v2.16a rotated objects in LaTeX
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
   color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 wrapfig.sty    
booktabs.sty    2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
algpseudocode.sty    
algorithmicx.sty    2005/04/27 v1.2 Algorithmicx
 parskip.sty    2001/04/09 non-zero parskip adjustments
flushend.sty    1997/10/01
lstlang1.sty    2013/08/26 1.5b listings language file
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
  ot1pcr.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/pcr.
  omsptm.fd    
lstlang1.sty    2013/08/26 1.5b listings language file
 lstmisc.sty    2013/08/26 1.5b (Carsten Heinz)
  paper.bbl
 ***********
```

Comment: This is most likely *not* related to the version of pdftex but due changes in the class or some package or font you use.

Comment: I also thought that the reason was the class file, but this was not true. The problem persists even when I use absolute paths to poin to latest IEEE class file. When I compare the first pages of two files, there are 3 lines in the 10-page file go into the second page of the 11-page counterpart, and there is no figure, table or any thing fancy in the first page, only text.

Comment: Use `\listfiles` to compare the versions of the packages used.

Comment: you give the version of tex (but that's almost certainly not relevant) what is the version of latex? is it a two column document with one latex being 2015/01/01 ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I updated my question with the full output. Yes, it is a IEEE two-column document. The one with 11-page is created by latex in my office. I used this machine from 2011, so it is likely before 2015/01/01 (unless the system administrator updated it without my knowledge).

Comment: no sorry that is still no information about the latex version (despite the fact you use pdflatex -version you just get the underlying tex version there) the top of the log will say something like `LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>` but if it isn't 2015 unlikely to be the issue so as Martin said, add `\listfiles` and show all your package versions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I understand now, on top of the log is: LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>. It is too old, so this is the problem? But I have used it for more than 3 years without problem.

Comment: the version of latex is actually unlikely to make any difference except a possible change in the 2015 release which was why I asked about that, If as requested above you add `\listfiles` to your document the log will show a log of all packages used with their version numbers you can compare the two versions that you have.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I updated my questions with file lists for two cases. But there are different versions in so many packages, so I don't know which packages caused the difference in the number of pages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The latex at my home is newer, but not latest. It is LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>.

Comment: most likely the class file, the first listing is using a version of ieeetran.cls that isn't reporting a version at all which is decidedly odd or old or both.

Comment: You seem to have massively different file versions on the two systems: you will probably need to work through one file at a time to track down where the change is, but like @DavidCarlisle I suspect the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I intended to delete this question, because the problem is due to my careless mistake. But I think it can still have useful information so I keep it, and I answer my own question because I don't want to leave it open.*

As many people have pointed out, the reason is due to the difference in the class files.

The latest version of the template in IEEE homepage is: *IEEEtran.cls 2011/11/03*
http://www.ieee.org/documents/unix_latex_template.tar.gz

However, in the instruction sent to me by the editor, the template is *IEEEtran.cls 2007/03/05*
ftp://pubftp.computer.org/Press/Outgoing/proceedings/IEEE_CS_LatexA4x2.zip

I was stupid to think they were the same organization, and the templates would be the same.

Now I know the cause, but I get confused about which template to use. If I use the old one following the instructions of the editor, I need to cut nearly one page of my paper, which is very difficult. But of course, this is not a suitable question on this site.